# Seleccionar celdas especificas de un archivo csv

Tags: csv

mi duda es la siguiente:
Necesito seleccionar celdas especificas de un archivo .csv e insertarlas en celdas especificas en otro archivo .csv, ejemplo seleccionar el nombre de una persona que se encuentra en la columna 2 fila 7 e insertarla en la columna 7 fila 48,la herramienta es talend

Comment: Bienvenido, que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: muchas gracias, no he intentado nada, soy nuevo en esa herramienta y no tengo la menos idea de como realizarlo